# Escape post image attachments added to template

Tags: php, images, escaping

What is the secure way to use wp_get_attachment_image() in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the output through escaping function should be just fine.
You can either use `wp_kses_post()`, which by default allows the same html attributes that you would use in the post content ([see in code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/)):

```
echo wp_kses_post( wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id ) );
```

or if you want to be more precise and strict, you can pass an [array with allowed attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) for that particular context, like so:

```
echo wp_kses( wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id ), [
    'img' => [
        'src'      => true,
        'srcset'   => true,
        'sizes'    => true,
        'class'    => true,
        'id'       => true,
        'width'    => true,
        'height'   => true,
        'alt'      => true,
        'loading'  => true,
        'decoding' => true,
    ],
] );
```

It's up to you to decide what is allowed, just change the array contents to adjust to your needs!

Comment: Just in case it helps someone avoid some debugging time, wp_kses_post() removes the srcset and sizes attributes, so you will lose responsive images support by using it. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29807.

Answer (score 0):

For now (28 of May 2021) `wp_kses` does not output `srcset` and `sizes` attributes (although ticket [created ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29807) 7 years ago...).

But it's easy to enable via filter:

```
function starter_wpkses_post_tags( $tags, $context ) {
    $tags['img']['sizes']  = true;
    $tags['img']['srcset'] = true;
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'starter_wpkses_post_tags', 10, 2 );
```

Nowadays all modern browsers supports **webp** so it could be useful also to enable additional attributes for `source` tag, so full solution for `srcset` and `sizes` for both `img` and `source` tags is:

```
function starter_wpkses_post_tags( $tags, $context ) {
    $tags['img']['sizes']  = true;
    $tags['img']['srcset'] = true;
    $tags['source'] = array(
        'srcset' => true,
        'sizes'  => true,
        'type'   => true,
    );
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'starter_wpkses_post_tags', 10, 2 );
```